# Nash Equilibrium in Cournot Duopoly

Tags: economics, nash-equilibrium

If you have a demand function Q1= 20 + 3/4 p2 - p1  and Q2= 20 + 3/4 p1 - p2, how does one go about solving for the Nash equilibrium if you know there are no costs?

I've tried solving for Q and then taking the derivative; however, I'm left with the extra price variable of the other firm's price.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You have two demand functions. Does that mean that the firms are competing in two markets, choosing a quantity for each?

Comment: It is a simultaneous game (Cournot). They're selling similar but not identical goods; the demand goes up if the other firm's price goes up and vice versa.

Comment: Firms are in the same market.

Comment: This is price competition. You need to compute each firm's best response function $p_i(p_{-i})$. By definition, NE is given by $p_i (p_{-i} (p_i)) = p_i$, i.e. each firm $i$ has no incentive to deviate.

Comment: Price competition is part of a Bertrand game. As this is asking for the solution to a Cournot game, you should take the demand functions (written as a system of linear equations here) and invert them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the given demand functions, written as a system of linear equation, and invert them. Write $p_1$ and $p_2$ as a function of total firm output. That is, solve for $p_1$ and $p_2$ as a function of $Q_1=q_1^a + q_1^b$ and $Q_2=q_2^a + q_2^b$.

Next, maximize the profit function of firm A over $q_1^a$ and $q_2^a$ given the output of firm B, $q_1^b$ and $q_2^b$. Do the same for B given A. This will give you four first-order conditions, with $q_1^a, q_2^a, q_1^b,$ and $q_2^b$ as the four unknowns that you will solve for.

**EDIT:** As a hint, you should begin by inverting the system of demand equations
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
Q_1 \\
Q_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 3/4 \\
3/4 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
p_1 \\
p_2
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
20 \\
20
\end{bmatrix}
$$
to get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
p_1 \\
p_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-16/7 & -12/7 \\
-12/7 & -16/7 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
Q_1 \\
Q_2
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
80 \\
80
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now, the prices are written in terms of quantity only. You can then proceed to find the first-order conditions for each firm, $a$ and $b$. The maximization problem for firm $a$, written in matrix notation, is given below:
$$
\max_{\vec q_a}\vec q_a^\intercal P(\vec q_a + \vec q_b) = \vec q_a^\intercal (A(\vec q_a + \vec q_b) + b).
$$
With both sets of first-order conditions, you will end up with 4 equations and 4 unknowns that will have a unique solution.

Comment: Sorry--the formatting is real messy; hopefully this helps:

How do I eliminate variables though?

Here's what I did: 
Step 1. q1+q2 = 40 - 1/4 p2 - 1/4 p1
Step 2. 1/4 p1 = 40 - 1/4 p2 - q1 - q2
Step 3. p1 = 160 - p2 - 1/4 q1 - 1/4 q2
Step 4. p2 = 160 - p1 - 1/4 q1 - 1/4 q2

Step 5. profit = pq
Step 6.(160 - p2 - 1/4 q1 - 1/4 q2) q1
Step 7. 160 q1 - p2 q1 - 1/4 q1^2 - 1/4 q1q2

Step 8. First Order Condition: 160 - p2 - 1/2 q1 - 1/4 q2

Step 9. Repeat for second...

Step 10. 160 - p1 - 1/4q1 - 1/2q2

Comment: I then tried setting the first order conditions equal to each other and then substitute the p1 and p2 I found earlier to find the respective quantities but I end up in a circle once I substitute in the p1 and p2 (I get p1 - p2 + 3/4 q1 + 3/4 q2 = 0. I also tried setting p1 equal to p2 but found that looped back to q1 = q2

Comment: I added an edit that should help. You can write the maximization problem out so that it's not in matrix notation. But it helps to see the general principle. Hope this helps!

Comment: So I understand how you laid it out in matrix form; how are you getting from that step to the next step? If I understand correctly wouldn't Q1 = 20 - p1 + 3/4 p1 = 20 - 1/4 p1 ==> p1 = 80 - 4 Q1 and due to symmetry p2 = 80 - 4q2? Solving for FOC there gives me q1 = 10 and q2 = 10. How would you go about writing the maximizatio problem not in matrix notation? Reason why I ask is because whenever we've done Cournot or Bertrand in the past we've never had to use matrices so they are a bit foreign to me.

Comment: So what I did was I solved for p1 and p2 and got p2 and p1. Then I used those with the profit function to get the FOC, then added the two FOC together and assumed q1 = q2 to find q*. Is that a sound methodology?

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you!